# Logstash seemingly changes the Elasticsearch output URL

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have my Logstash configured with the following output:

```
output {
    hosts => ["http://myhost/elasticsearch"]
}
```

This is a valid URL, as I can cURL commands to Elasticsearch with it, such as

```
curl "http://myhost/elasticsearch/_cat/indices?v"
```

returns my created indices.

However, when Logstash attempts to create a template, it uses the following URL:

```
http://myhost/_template/logstash
```

when I would expect it to use

```
http://myhost/elasticsearch/_template/logstash
```

It appears that the /elasticsearch portion of my URL is being chopped off. What's going on here? Is "elasticsearch" a reserved word in the URL that is removed? As far as I can tell, when I issue `http://myhost/elasticsearch/elasticsearch`, it attempts to find an index named "elasticsearch" which leads me to believe it isn't reserved.

Upon changing the endpoint URL to be

```
http://myhost/myes
```

Logstash is still attempting to access

```
http://myhost/_template/logstash
```

What might be the problem?

**EDIT**
Both Logstash and Elasticsearch are v5.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified which version of logstash you are using.  If you are using one of the 2.x versions, you need to use use the `path => '/myes/'` parameter to specify that your ES instance is behind a proxy.  In 2.x, the `hosts` parameter was just a list of hosts, not URIs.

Comment: I am running ES and LS v5.0.0; however, breaking out the 'path' seemed to work in my case. Thanks!